# Como pasar parámetros (que son propiedades de un objeto) a una funcion JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de pasar como parámetro a una funcion, propiedades de un objeto para hacer el filter , sin embargo el parámetro key no lo toma, y siemre me muestra como resultado un array vacío.

Gracias por la ayuda

```
 let suscritos = [
        {
          nombre: "Mario",
          membresia: "oro"
        },
        {
            nombre: "Andrea",
            membresia: "platino"
        },
        {
            nombre: "David",
            membresia: "platino"
        },
    
    ];
    
    let filter_suscribers = (key, item) => {
        const result = suscritos.filter(c => c.key === item);
        console.log(result);
    }
    
    filter_suscribers('membresia', 'oro')
```

Comment: Tu *array* se llama `suscritos`. Tu código pone `personas`. Y no es `c.key`, es `c[key]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que simplemente estas complicando la logica de la aplicacion, lo que realmente deberias de estar haciendo es lo siguiente.

```js
let suscritos = [
        {
          nombre: "Mario",
          membresia: "oro"
        },
        {
            nombre: "Andrea",
            membresia: "platino"
        },
        {
            nombre: "David",
            membresia: "platino"
        },
    
];
    
let filter_suscribers = (key, item) => {
  const result = suscritos.filter(c => c.membresia === item);
  console.log(result);
}

filter_suscribers('membresia', 'oro')
```

En caso de que realmente quieras pasar el key de forma dinamica tendria que ser de la siguiente manera.

```js
let suscritos = [
            {
              nombre: "Mario",
              membresia: "oro"
            },
            {
                nombre: "Andrea",
                membresia: "platino"
            },
            {
                nombre: "David",
                membresia: "platino"
            },
        
    ];
        
    let filter_suscribers = (key, item) => {
      const result = suscritos.filter(c => c[key] === item);
      console.log(result);
    }
    
    filter_suscribers('membresia', 'oro')
```

Esta es la forma en la que javascript podra reconocer ese parametro como un key pasado por parametro, en caso de que tengas mas dudas deja un comentario y modifico mi respuesta.

Por ultimo, no se si tratabas de llamar en la funcion a un arreglo llamado personas que existe en tu programa o realmente debias de mandar a llamar el arreglo suscritos.

Comment: Hola el array es suscritos me equivoqué y le puse otro nombre, gracias por la respuesta